# How can I get transparent images to appear on TMenu item

Tags: delphi

I have recently converted from Image Lists to Virtual Image Lists and Image Collection controls. All my images are stored in the TImageCollection as png files with transparency.  They render fine on the toolbar tool buttons but these same images are not rendered as transparent images with TMainMenu.  Do I need to render all menus using Owner Draw?

Comment: Menus are already owner drawn when images are assigned. I haven't tried the new Virtual Image List yet, but if images render transparent on a ToolBar but not a MainMenu, that sounds like a bug that Embarcadero needs to address

Comment: This seems to work for me out of the box (Delphi 10.3.3).  I have tried it with a TActionMainMenuBar and a TPopupMenu with no code, just assigning the TVirtualimageList and selecting an ImageIndex value in the Object Inspector.  Nothing owner drawn.  Are you using a TVirtualImageList?

Comment: I'm using 10.3.3 and the TMainMenu component.  Never used the TActcionMainMenuBar, perhaps I should give it a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embarcadero only add the TImageCollection and TVirtualImageList components (the old component does not change). Lot of old components do not call the DoDraw method from the TImageList or TVirtualImageList component (almost each use own method for transparency). Even the components calling the DoDraw method from TImageList don't always work correctly (problems with styles).

They also use 'outdated' methods for transparent images (do not use alpha blending almost in all old components).

I make own descending components (transparent image, speed button, toolbar, tree view, tabcontrol), TImageCollection and TVirtualImageList. But not the TMenu component (use only my version of TImageCollection and TVirtualImageList) because TMenu calls the DoDraw method from TImageList/TVirtualImageList for drawing icons.

I think Embarcadero must change drawing pictures in components. They need call DoDraw method from TImageList/TVirtualImageList in all components with pictures.

Comment: Are you saying the standard TMenu control does deliver transparency with TVirtualImageList but other controls don't?

Comment: No, i say you do not need change TMenu control, you only need create own descending TVirtualImageList. Other control must be changed (i create own descending controls).